# Скрипт для поиска файлов в каталоге, превосходящих заданный размер

Tags: linux, bash, find

Мне нужно написать скрипт, получающий имя каталога и размер N в мегабайтах и ищущий в этом каталоге все файлы превосходящие по размеру N. Помимо этого каждый из найденных файлов нужно упаковать в архив(в каталоге где он был найден), затем удалить исходный файл и создать пустой с таким же именем. Отчет обо всей работе надо скидывать в файл /var/log/Miso.log.

Проблема в том, что скрипт начинает выводить имена файлов не только в файл Miso.log, но ещё и в терминал. Как оставить лишь вывод в файл? И можно ли сразу начать архивировать файлы в строке с командой find?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter path"
read path
echo "Your path is $path"
echo "Enter size"
read size
echo "Your size is $size"
size=$(( $size * 1024))
find $path -size +"$size"k | sudo tee /var/log/Miso.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так и сделайте перенаправление напрямую в файл:

```sh
 find $path -size +"$size"k > /var/log/Miso.log
```

Или, если вам так уж нужно *sudo*:

```sh
 find $path -size +"$size"k | sudo tee /var/log/Miso.log > /dev/null
```